# How to remove logo in SharePoint Online Header?

Tags: sharepoint-online, style.css, customization

As we have the logo in the O365 navigation header, we would like to remove the one in the SharePoint header.

I was able to do it using CSS; however, it does feel like a hack and I wonder if there i a best way to do it.

```
.logoCell-48, .logoCell-49, .logoCell-50, .logoCell-76, .logoCell-77, .logoCell-78, .logoCell-80, .logoCell-82, .logoCell-167 {
    display: none !important;
}
```

As you can see the logoCell class can have different names and there is a high risk of not covering all possible class names.

Should I automate this to create a css class with all possible numbers from logoCell-X to logoCell-Y? Maybe 30 to 200. It would look ugly.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your CSS like below:

```
div[class^="logoCell"] {
    display: none !important;
}
```

`^=` is called as starts with selector in CSS or JQuery. Read more about it in CSS below:

[CSS [attribute^=value] Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp).

Comment: That is brilliant ! Thanks